# can i make a server side form validation in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am using httpUrlConnection in android to send a user form (name,pre name,email etc) to the server then validation is done at server side, after that form data are inserted to data base or an error returned to user. that is what my php page looks like in brief

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$prename = $_POST['prename'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if( isvalid($name)&&isvalid($prename)&&isvalid($email) ){
    insertUser($name,$prename,$email);
    echo 'successfully registered'
}else{
    echo 'data invalid please correct';
}
?>
```

theoretically , now user cant insert malformed data like a name that contain numbers into my database.
even if a hacker could trick the host server into accepting such malformed input then mysql server will return an error that said could not insert those data into corresponding fields since every column has a predefined type in mysql.

**now i considered to switch to firebase** and i wonder if i can do the same verification before inserting the data into my realtime database ***without relying on client side verification***. i mean if someone crack my app or bypass the verification on the client side(witch is easy for a hacker) and trick the app he could be able to insert some malformed data and users will start to see name that contain numbers or phone number that contain letter or have a password that have one letter and i dont want that to happen.

my question is: is there any way to verify the users inputs before inserting them to my firebase without a client side verification?
if not then what is the best way to get around that 'problem'?

Sorry for Lengthening,but i tried to be precise as mutch as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate the data that can be written into the Firebase Realtime Database, you can use Firebase's server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). These are evaluated before every read/write to the database, and you can use them to ensure all data is valid, and all access is authorized.

For some examples, have a look at the Firebase documentation on [validating the data with security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules).